# How to insert an initial value for an async list in an ng-select (Angular 2+, ng-select, and rxjs)

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject, rxjs-observables, angular-ngselect

I am using [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) and specifically using typeahead to fetch the list from the server as user types. like this:

defining an observable of Agents list to subscribe to whenever a string is inserted

```
agents$: Observable<Agent[]>
agentsInput$ = new Subject<string>();
```

notice here i am mapping the Agents to a specific desired object:

```
loadAgents() {
    this.agents$ = concat(
      of([]),
      this.agentsInput$.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => this.agentsLoading = true),
        switchMap(term => this.obexService.searchAgents(term).pipe(
          map(agent => agent.map(agent => ({
            id: agent._id,
            name: `${agent.firstName} ${agent.lastName}`
          }))),
          catchError(() => of([])), // empty the agents list on error
          tap(() => this.agentsLoading = false)
        ))
      )
    )
  }
```

here is the HTML:

```
<ng-select 
    id="contact-person" 
    labelForId="contact-person" 
    [items]="agents$ | async" 
    bindValue="id" 
    bindLabel="name"
    [loading]="agentsLoading" 
    typeToSearchText="Please enter 3 or more characters"
    [typeahead]="agentsInput$" 
    class="custom" 
    notFoundText="Agent Not Found"
    formControlName="contactAgent" 
    placeholder="Select a contact person">
  </ng-select>
```

basiclly what I am trying to do is to insert an initial list to agents$, so that to be able to set a default agent on the form control, so I want to turn the agent$ into behaviuor subject

sonmething like this:

```
agents$: BehaviorSubject<Agent[]> = new BehaviorSubject([{id: '123', name: 'john doe'}])
```

Now I have 2 problems:

1- how do I map agents on setting initial value the same way I mapped them in `loadAgents()` method?

2- The telesense shows the below error when setting the `agents$` in the `loadAgents()` method

> Type 'Observable<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type
> 'BehaviorSubject<Agent[]>': _value, value, getValue, next, and 9
> more.ts(2740)

please advise.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you don't need the behavior subject. just the `of` observable should work for your case

```
agents$ = new of<Agent[]>([{id: '123', name: 'john doe'}]); // correct type will be applied in this case. no need to define it explicitly.
...
```

also for `concact(of(something), ...)` case there is a built in operator `startWith`

```
loadAgents() {
    this.agents$ = this.agentsInput$.pipe(
        // your code
        startWith<Agent[]>([])
      );
```